# Contest Math Geometry

Tags: geometry, contest-math

I'm currently prepping for some high school math competitions soon, and I was wondering if anyone knows any resources that are out there with an abundance of contest-math-related geometry problems. Geometry is definitely my weak point in contest math, and any input would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There's a book by T. Andreescu that is aimed at high school students, called Mathematical Olympiad Challenges.

Comment: You've probably seem [gogeometry.com](http://gogeometry.com/geometry/index.html).

Comment: Wow, both look like great resources.

Comment: Geometry Revisited is the classic

Comment: @lyj, who is the author?

Comment: Coxeter and Greizer

Comment: Both Geometry Revisited and Geometry Unbound are books I've heard good things about. They are both available online at 
http://analgeomatica.files.wordpress.com/2008/11/geometryrevisited_coxetergreitzer_0883856190.pdf
and
http://www-math.mit.edu/~kedlaya/geometryunbound/gu-060118.pdf

Answer (score 3):

A good place to start is http://www.artofproblemsolving.com which covers all kinds of contest math.

Answer (score 1):

A good series of books with increasingly difficult problems is the 101 problems in algebra, 102 problems in combinatorics, etc. by Titu Andreescu and Zuming Feng